# Which browsers' back button does not generate request to the server?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers

I need to test my web application against a browser for which back button doesn't generate request to server.

Could you give me examples of such browsers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That doesn't depend on the browser used, but on the HTTP response headers sent to it. If the browser is by the response headers instructed to cache the page, then it will cache the page. But if it is instructed to not cache the page, then it will not cache the page and fire a real request.

[You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) have control over the response headers on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer 6, not sure about 7/8. Make sure you dont have the following meta statements in your header (they will force page reload):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Check this page for more info:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067

Comment: I can't easily install specific version of IE on my machine. Are there other browsers? Some ancient FF for example

Comment: @Luis: See the link in my answer. @Wheleph: use [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) or a VM.

Comment: You can use IE tester, which contains all the version of ie:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: @BalusC thanks, you can control that from server side, but ie by default caches pages when using browser naviugation, i think this is the OP as asked originally.

Comment: When you use the wrong/incomlplete resposne headers, yes. It's not only IE, but every browser which adheres the HTTP spec.

Comment: Are u sure Balus? From memory i recall having issues with ie with page caching and not with firefox when developing in ASP.NET, but maybe that has to do with the default headers sent to the browser...