# Chorme the back button is making request

Tags: button, back

I'm having the following problem.  I have an application developed in ASP.NET MVC 4 with C #.

Suppose we have the Index pages, page_1, page_2 and page_3. Right.
Now the Index page we have a button that redirects you to the product registration page (page_1) when registering the product redirects to the product price registration page (page_2) when registering the price and when registering the price redirects to the product detail screen (page_3).

The problem is this: when I'm already on the product detail screen (page_3) and I click the back button (browser), it makes a request.

This only happens in Chrome version 44.0.2403.157 m in EI 11 this does not happen.

Because of this requisition on my Action (HttpGet) is giving error object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I'm using TempData [""].

I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how the browser cached the original HttpGet response. [See this post for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722261/what-browsers-back-button-doesnt-generate-request-to-server/2722280#2722280)

While you can force a browser to **not** cache a response, you cannot reliably depend on a browser to pull a response from its cache, as it may have been invalidated for reasons beyond your control.