# How to handle browser back button using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, servlets

I am using spring mvc and i am facing the problem with browser back button

When user click on back button It is not hitting server.
I have return both GET and POST methods to handle this,but it is not hitting the server itself.
After removing the cache from client side by using filter also .It is not working

Can any one suggest what has to be done to resolve the issue?
Thanks in Advance

*************Filter to remove the cache****************

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Removing the cache from Request");
    HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)res;
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("max-age", 0);
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

********** Controller to handle GET and POST request ********

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String method()
{
    LOG.info("### Handling Get Request Started ###");

    return "/myPage";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/myPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlePostMethod(MyForm form,
        final BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    LOG.info("### Handling Post Request Started ###");
    return "/myPage"
}
```

Response headers:

```
POST /shop/login/cstbasereginputagree HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost:9002 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 119
Cache-Control: max-age=0 Origin: localhost:9002
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

************* Web.xml ****************

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>NoBrowserCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.web.filters.NoBrowserCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NoBrowserCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What browsers' Back button doesn't generate request to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722261/what-browsers-back-button-doesnt-generate-request-to-server)

Comment: Thanks for response Sidgate , But even after removing the cache also through filter it is not working.

Comment: Did i am doing wrong any thing in removing cache by filter? and even i tried in incognito window also

Comment: If you view the response headers using your browser's developer tools, do you see the additional headers in there?

Comment: POST /shop/login/cstbasereginputagree HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9002
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 119
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://localhost:9002
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

Comment: Above is my request headers, we can notice that **Cache-Control: max-age=0**

Comment: Response Headers :Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Language:ja
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 25 Jul 2016 12:07:05 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
max-age:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=02E0836D77DB617C00F7A12012AADD57; Path=/shop; Secure; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: Above is my Response Headers with **Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache**

Comment: Can you please guide where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Edit additional details into your question, I did it for you this time. As you can see in the headers, they are absolutely not the ones you set in the filter. So I'm going to guess you forgot something to activate it. Do you have a WebFilter annotation on it or configure it in the web.xml ?

Comment: But i configured in web.xml also and even my filter is calling when i put debug

Comment: **As you can see in the headers, they are absolutely not the ones you set in the filter**. Can i know which parameter i can check whether it is caching or not?